# optimization algorithm for grouping sets of numbers

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis

There is N subsets of natural numbers between 1 and K (sample set: {2,9,32}). Number of items/numbers in each set varies, but it cannot exceed K. 50% of subsets are 1- or 2-element sets. The distribution can be visualised as 

`number of elem.|frequency
              1 #########################
              2 ##############
              3 #####
              4 ###
            ...
              n #`

We can combine sets - this is just a simple union of sets, i.e. if A = {1,2,5,6}, B = {2,6,33} then A + B = {1,2,5,6,33}.

We have to cluster these sets so in each cluster the number of elements is minimal and there's minimum P elements in each cluster.

For example: A = {1,2,3}, B = {5,6}, C = {7,8}, D = {9,10,11} the output should be: group 1: AB, group 2: CD (or AC and BD) - we have 2 groups with 5 elements. Grouping AD and BC is not optimal because we have 6 and 4 elements respectively.

N and P can be arbitrary numbers, in my case `25000<N<35000`, `10<P<30`. The problem is very practical, not only a math task.

How can I approach this? What alghoritm is most appropriate?